# discord.py Cog // how to send message to specific channe

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    channel = self.client.get_channel(797863482380124170)
    if message.channel.id in talk_channel:
        stats = levelling.find_one({"id": message.author.id})
        if not message.author.bot:
            if stats is None:
                newuser = {"id": message.author.id, "xp": 100}
                levelling.insert_one(newuser)
            else:
                xp = stats["xp"] + 100
                levelling.update_one({"id": message.author.id}, {"$set": {"xp": xp}})
                lvl = 0
                while True:
                    if xp < ((50 ** (lvl ** 2)) + (50 * lvl)):
                        break
                    lvl += 1
                    # lvl += 1
                xp -= ((50 * ((lvl - 1) ** 2)) + (50 * (lvl - 1)))
                
                if xp == 0:
                    await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} Lvl Up!")
```

So this is my code but **await message.channel.send** doesnt work plz help me

i tried lots of Way but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

`await channel.send()` should be fine. You can read more here: [discordpy.readthedocs.io](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)

Comment: I think channel won't work because OP has already defined `channel = self.client.get_channel(797863482380124170)`, which is not necessarily the same channel as the one in which the message event took place.